# How can I stop an alert from being a function?

Tags: javascript, function, alert

When I tried to run my code:

```
var intro = function () {
  alert('Welcome');
  alert('Hello!');
};

intro();
```

In the browser console, it gave me the error that alert was not a function. Along with all the other alerts in my code. How could I change these alerts and all of my other alerts so that the console doesn't think they're functions?

I'm sorry if this is a bad question, I am a beginner to JS.

Edit: the reason the alerts are in the function is because I thought that that could solve the problem and it didn't.

Comment: Why aren't they functions? What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome and I'm asking why the console thinks the alerts are functions, when they aren't intended to be.

Comment: `alert`s are functions. What did you think they're when you called them in your code as functions?

Comment: `alert('Welcome')` *is* a function call. You're calling the function named `alert` with the string argument `'Welcome'`. The error isn't telling you that `alert` is a function. It's telling you that `alert` *isn't* a function—although ordinarily it is—so we must ask, what is it? What does `console.log(alert)` tell you?

Comment: How can I fix it so It alerts the text ('Welcome') to the user instead of being an error. @Jordan

Comment: \*ahem\* What does `console.log(alert)` tell you?

Comment: You have probably overrided it somewhere. Do you have some expression that looks like `alert = ...` or `function alert ...` somewhere in your code?

Comment: I looked at my code and I hadn't realized that  much later on I had done some edits and deleting and somehow an alert got assigned a value. Oops. Thanks for the fix :D @Ibrahim mahrir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One and only way to reproduce this case for me is:

```js
alert = "cv634v5ctwhatever";

var intro = function () {
  alert('Welcome');
  alert('Hello!');
};

intro();
```

Try to figure out when you or some others assign a value to the `alert` in code.